# PyQt under Windows 7 doesn't show nothing

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to use Qt environment inside my Python projects to make a simple application that shows some plots. Therefore, I have implemented one version of this app under Ubuntu and all seems to work how I want, but when I transfer the same application under Windows 7 OS and build it, nothing appears. The relative python.exe process is in the Task Manager list and when I close it, in my editor (Sublime Text 2) appears the termination message `[Finished in 9.9s with exit code 1]` (for example).
So I tried to build a simple example code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but nothing appears. The strange is that if I run `pyqtgraph.examples` (PyQtGraph is a library based on PyQt for dynamic plotting) in the command line

```
python -m pyqtgraph.examples
```

all seems to work properly: it shows the application main window where I can navigate through some examples. Now my question is: WHY? I don't understand where is the problem.
Can anyone tell me if under Windows 7 this is normal?

Comment: how about use QWindow but widget as main window?

Comment: @ReadonShaw I have tryed even with `w = QtGui.QMainWindow()` (PyQt4 hasn't a Qwindow class) but still nothing. I picked up the example above from a tutorial site [Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/) only to try if works. I don't understand why under Ubuntu is ok but under Windows no.

Comment: _when I close it, in my editor (Sublime Text 2) appears the termination message_ Do run it from an editor?

Comment: @MikeMüller Yes. It supports the build for various languages (in my opinion is an awesome editor, I came from emacs). However, it couldn't be the editor since the problem remains even if I launch the program from the console.